# The Area51 ads produce an error on per-site community ads

Tags: bug, area-51, images, advertising, community-promotion-ads

The Area 51 ads, when you click on Share This, provide a link and an image, as well as the corresponding HTML, to advertise elsewhere. This used to work, but when copypasting the image link (that looks something like this: `http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/123456.png`) into a per-site [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) question, you get a "Not from Imgur" error. Can't SE itself be added to the whitelisted image hosts?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't see that, thx!

Comment: No worry, I remembered seeing it recently, otherwise wouldn't think to search.